# What is the difference between Data Wrangling and ETL (Extract, Transform, and Load)?

Tags: apache-spark, etl, data-science

My basic understanding of ETL is that someone like a Data Analyst would use it. ETL would be used to extract data from a database (MySQL), transformed into something like Excel, where business rules (Excel functions) are applied, and then loaded into a new database for another application. I'm incredibly confused when it comes to how this is different than data wrangling. From what I've gathered there are only a few difference. 1, the people using the technologies are different. Data Wrangling may be the work of Data Engineer vs. ETL and Data Analysts. 2, the technologies used are different. Data Wrangling would use something like Apache Spark or the Hadoop Ecosystem. ETL would use tools like Excel, Access, or a cloud database to extract data. Essentially, my understanding is that data wrangling is "ETL-ing" with raw data, meaning the data hasn't been modeled - (it is not in a schema). (Maybe you would have to parse the data like retweets, likes, and favorites or something when wrangling)? Just curious if I'm on the track or not. I've tried reading some articles but it still doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone provide a simple explaination so I can wrap my head around the concept? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Wrangling is the process of transforming/cleansing data this flows from a source to a target. There are multiple ways to do this transformation or cleansing:-

## "Small" Datasets

For small datasets that can be opened in an excel, the transformations of cleansing rules can be defined in excel through the help of macros etc. If you want to keep doing this repeatedly you can build bat (windows) or shell (linux) scripts and schedule them through a cron or windows scheduler.

A trivial example would be to replace NULL with some value in a file which is 10 MB in size

## "Medium" Datasets

When the dataset size is such that it cannot be opened in excel you can then use scripting or programming languages to do the same operation and schedule them using the schedulers mentioned example. Such scripting languages are typically running on a single machine and the performance is directly proportional to the configuration of the machine

A trivial example would be to replace NULL with some value in a file which is 10 GB in size

## "Large" Datasets

When the dataset is large, opening in excel is not possible and running the cleansing rule on a single machine can be slow. This is where `Big Data`  technologies such as Map reduce, Spark etc shine where a subset of data is sent to multiple machines and the cleansing rule is applied on each machine on the subset of data thereby increasing the throughput of the entire processing.

A trivial example would be to replace NULL with some value in a file which is 500 GB in size

Comment: So the difference is the technologies you use and what you are doing with that data, but the process is essentially the same?